# .Net application not getting connected to SQL Server after upgrade to SQL Server 2014 SP3

Tags: sql-server, ssl, patch, tls1.2, database-administration

ASP.NET Web API application abruptly stopped working after a recent upgrade of an on-premise SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014 (SP3) (KB4022619) - 12.0.6024.0 (X64).

The application is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1.

I am able to connect to this server using SSMS from my local machine. The connection also succeeds if I host the application on Windows Server 2012.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Based on the application error getting logged, I get a feeling that it is something related to TLS/SSL. But I am not sure which patches are to be installed on Application server and SQL Server to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Additional info: the application also connects to another Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64). This works fine.

Comment: You need to [patch Windows Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi) to support TLS1.2. BTW Windows 2008R2 is *also* out of mainstream support. Even Extended support [ends this year](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2008). You should migrate to a fresh OS *and* SQL Server version. By moving to 2014 when 2017 is available you're literally burning money. The licensing cost is the same but performance will be inferior

Comment: Some features like unique indexes on top of columnstores can only be emulated by running code to detect duplicates after the fact. You'd really be using power (ie money) to do what's already available cheaply in a newer version.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much for your input. I'll check with the server team if they can help me with this patch. I am not quite sure about the licensing part, but I will surely communicate this to the client.

Comment: There's no reason for uncertainty. The 2008 R2 versions are ancient and their end-of-life announced years in advance. Microsoft launched a big PR campaign urging people to migrate in the last year. Remaining on Windows 2008 R2 locks you to SQL Server 2014 too, as newer SQL Server versions require Windows 2012 at least - itself a 7-year old OS.

Comment: And SQL Server 2014 SP3 mainstream support ends next Tuesday. [This is not a joke](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/1044). You probably won't be able to patch the server before the "new" database goes out of support too